# Solidity event isn't fired

Tags: node.js, events, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to listen for an event I've created on remix IDE , from NodeJS.
I call a smart contract method from where the event is triggered and I'm waiting for it in my console...but I don't receive anything :(

I'm using NodeJS with ExpressJS
Web3  Version:  1.0.0-beta.46

The Smart contract code would be something like :

```
pragma solidity >= 0.4.22 < 0.6.0;

contract Test {


event test1(address a,uint16 b,uint16 c,uint16 d,uint16 e);
event test2(address a,uint128 f,uint16 g);
event test3(address a,uint128 f,bool h);

//method 1
function method1(uint16 a,uint16 b,uint16 c,uint16 d) external payable {
// ... some code ... //

//here I trigger the event
    emit test1(msg.sender,a,b,c,d);
}

//method 2
function method2(uint128 f,uint16 g) external payable {
// ... some code ... //

//here I trigger the event
    emit test2(msg.sender,f,g);
}

//method 3
function method3(uint128 f) external payable {
// ... some code ... //

//here I trigger the event
    emit test3(msg.sender,f,true);
}


}
```

And this is how I listen for the event , in NodeJS :

```
 SmartContract.events.test1({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'} , (error, event) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(event)); })
 .on('data', (event) => {
console.log("The event is : " + JSON.stringify(event));
 }).on('changed', (event) => {
console.log("Changed event : " + JSON.stringify(event));
 }).on('error', console.error);
```

I've tried to listen without any parameters like fromBlock or toBlock as well,but didn't work...
I don't get any error or something.
I start listening before to perform the smart contract method and after I perform it

the mined block received has the status "0x1" so the transaction was ok.But I don't know why the listener isn't working...

EDIT : Instantiation of the smart contract :

```
 const address = "0xB740096F1a6642190c816EfE37697891c65Afc92";
 const theABI = require('./getABI.js');
 var SmartContract = new web3.eth.Contract(theABI.getABI() , address);
```

The getABI.js file has just 1 function that returns the ABI.
I'm sure and I've just rechecked,the ABI contains the events.Here's a snippet of code from the ABI where an event is present:

```
    {
            "anonymous": false,
            "inputs": [
                    {
                            "indexed": false,
                            "name": "a",
                            "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                            "indexed": false,
                            "name": "f",
                            "type": "uint128"
                    },
                    {
                            "indexed": false,
                            "name": "g",
                            "type": "uint16"
                    }
            ],
            "name": "test2",
            "type": "event"
    },
```

Instantiation of web3 :

```
 const Web3 = require('web3');
 const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://IP SERVER:PORT");
```

I've also tried the following approach :

```
 // Receives all events from the smart contract
 const listener = SmartContract.events.allEvents({}, (error, event) =>{ console.log("THE CALLBACK EVENT IS : " + JSON.stringify(event)); })
 .on('data', async (event) => { console.log("THE EVENT IS : " + JSON.stringify(event)); })
 .on('receipt', async function(result) { console.log("THE RECEIPT EVENT IS : " + JSON.stringify(event)); })
 .on('transactionHash', function(hash){ console.log("THE HASH EVENT IS : " + JSON.stringify(event)); })
 .on('error', function(error){ console.log("THE ERROR EVENT IS : " + JSON.stringify(event)); });
```

Still no output from event listener...

Comment: Can you also post how you have instantiated the contract and using which provider?

Comment: Sorry for being late...I've updated my question.Could you please take one more look? @Jagrut

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved :

The mined smart contract address wasn't correct so the events were listening for nothing.